# Java Iterator Loop once, start in middle

Tags: java, loops, collections, iterator

I have an Iterator - placed somewhere in the middle of my collection.

I want to loop over the collection from there on, returning a special element if I find it.

If I reach !hasNext() then I want to start at the begining, but I want to stop if I reach the place where I started first.

The best Idea how to solve that seems currently to save the "first" (wherever the iterator pointed when I started) element and then stop if I find that one again.

And that works as long as items can occure only once in my collection (i.e. in a HasSet).

Any better ideas how to do such thing? Iterator doesn't seem to supply a pointer/number back to me that I could compare.

Comment: what is that for an iterator and what do you mean with ***an Iterator - placed somewhere in the middle of my collection***

Comment: Get the two sublists from `mid` to `end`, end from `start` to `mid`; then just iterate them separately.

Comment: a HashSet doesn't have a fixed iteration order and is therefor probably the worst example for that whole "iterator in the middle" thing. - But that aside: You could just count the number of items you iterated over and stop when you reach the size of the collection.

Comment: Is using Iterator a requirement? looks more like a for loop thing.

Comment: you guys are probably right - i shouldn't use iterator. Did it to not having to change too much code - but now I probably will.

Answer (score 2):

With Guava Iterators (Java 7):

```
Iterator<YourType> iterator = Iterators.concat(yourIteratorPlaceSomewhereInMiddle, Iterators.limit(yourCollection.iterator(), positionOfSomewhereInMiddle));
```

With Streams (Java 8):

```
Optional<YourType> theAnswer = IntStream.iterate(positionOfSomewhereInMiddle, pos -> ++pos)
                                        .map(pos -> pos % sizeOfCollection)
                                        .mapToObj(yourCollection::get)
                                        .limit(sizeOfCollection)
                                        .filter(element -> element is 42)
                                        .findFirst();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is a list, then it can be done with below code

```
private void Object traverseList(List namesList, int startIndex ) {
    int index = 0;
    Iterator iterator = namesList.listIterator(startIndex);
    while (iterator.hasNext() && index < namesList.size()){
        Object element = iterator.next();
        /*if(element.isSpecialElement()){
         return element;
         }
        */
        index++;
        System.out.println(element);
        if(!iterator.hasNext()){
            iterator = namesList.iterator();
        }
    }
}
```

Since you want to transverse all the elements in the list,  I am making use of list size. And during iteration, if the special element is found, it can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

To start to iterate a Set from a definedValue I do :

```
    public void iterate(Set<Sample> set, Sample definedValue){
        Iterator<Sample> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Sample currentSample = iterator.next();
            if(currentSample.equals(definedValue)){
                while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Sample sampleToConsider = iterator.next();
                //Then do anything
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution becomes more simple if you:

- Don't use `Iterator`, it makes it more complicated
- Use a `List` instead of `Set` as `Set` is ill-suited for this use case

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Set<String> yourStartingCollection = new HashSet<>();
      List<String> fooList = new ArrayList<>(yourStartingCollection);

      Optional<String> specialElement = findSpecialElementStartingFromMiddle(fooList);
      if (specialElement.isPresent()) {
          // found it!
      }
  }

  private static Optional<String> findSpecialElementStartingFromMiddle(List<String> elements) {
      int middleIndex = elements.size() / 2;
      Optional<String> result = Optional.empty();

      for (int i = middleIndex; i < elements.size(); i++) {
          String element = elements.get(i);
          if (isSpecial(element)) {
              result = Optional.of(element);
              break;
          }
      }

      if (result.isPresent()) {
          return result;
      }

      for (int i = 0; i < middleIndex; i++) {
          String element = elements.get(i);
          if (isSpecial(element)) {
              result = Optional.of(element);
              break;
          }
      }

      return result;
  }

  private static boolean isSpecial(String element) {
      return element.equals("I'm special");
  }
  ```